# Can Dokan be used to write File System Filters in C#?

Tags: c#, security, dokan, filefilter

I need to write File System Filters to hide all files/folders. Can I use Dokan library to write it using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File system drivers and file system filter drivers have different architectures. Consequently, you can't. The only option to have a FS filter without writing a kernel-mode driver (or take some other FS filter driver code and modify it) is use our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/).